# How to know when to place the helper verb prior to the end vs at the very end of the sentence?

Tags: word-order, modal-verb

I have noticed when one forms a more complicated sentence, that the helper verb seems to either go prior to the last 2 verbs, or at the very end of the sentence. These examples may help clarify what I mean:

> weil ich ihn aus dem Haus kommen sehen KONNTE
>
> dass er von ihr gesehen worden sein SOLL
>
> nachdem ich ihm aufräumen geholfen habe

versus:

> obwohl du uns HÄTTEST helfen sollen
>
> nachdem sie uns nicht HABEN einladen wollen
>
> bevor du das Glas HAST fallen lassen

How do you know when you put the helper modal verb prior to the final verbs vs. when you put the verb right at the end?

Explanations would be much appreciated - I've tried to figure out a pattern but I've been really struggling to see what the difference between the two differing structures are.

Comment: Here's what helped me get a nice perspective on this topic: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Praedikat/index.html#Anchor-Ausnahme-35882

Comment: Ich bin verwirrt, da es so aussieht, als ob alle Beispiele von der Seite genommen wurden, die @Grantwalzer verlinkt hat. Demnach müssen die Erklärungen dieser Seite bekannt sein und doch nicht geholfen haben?!

Comment: @Em1 Lol. Nochmal durchlesen :P

Comment: The rough-and-ready heuristic is that inversion happens when you have an *Ersatzinfinitiv* as the modal verb, but not for normal auxiliary verbs.

Comment: I don't think i understand the concept. In the above examples, "haben" has been either placed prior to the end verbs or is placed right at the end. How can you differentiate whether its functioning as a normal auxiliary verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nach diesem Schema kannst du die 2 Formen ineinander umformen:

```
weil ich ihn aus dem Haus kommen sehen KONNTE.
-> Ich konnte.   => Konnte WAS?
-> Ich konnte sehen. => Konnte WAS sehen?
-> Ich konnte kommen sehen.
=> weil ich ihn aus dem Haus KONNTE kommen sehen
```

Dann würde man für die anderen 5 Beispiele theoretisch bekommen:

```
dass er von ihr gesehen worden sein SOLL
dass er von ihr SOLL gesehen worden sein

nachdem ich ihm aufräumen geholfen HABE
nachdem ich ihm HABE aufräumen geholfen

obwohl du uns helfen {sollen HÄTTEST} <== FALSCH!
obwohl du uns HÄTTEST helfen sollen

nachdem sie uns nicht einladen {wollen HABEN} <== FALSCH!
nachdem sie uns nicht HABEN einladen wollen

bevor du das Glas fallen lassen HAST
bevor du das Glas HAST fallen lassen
```

Die zwei geklammerten Ausdrücke "sollen HÄTTEST" und "wollen HABEN" sind aber nicht möglich. Der Grund ist, dass "sollen" und "wollen" Modalverben<sup>[(1)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalverb)</sup> sind. Anstelle der zwei falschen Ausdrücke muss es für diese Verben wie folgt heißen:

```
obwohl du uns helfen solltest
obwohl du uns HÄTTEST helfen sollen

nachdem sie uns nicht einladen wollten
nachdem sie uns nicht HABEN einladen wollen
```

Die Wendungen "soll gesehen worden sein" und "habe aufräumen geholfen" (wie auch "nachdem ich ihm habe geholfen aufzuräumen") sind aber total unüblich bzw. sie klingen sehr poetisch und konstruiert. Auch erscheinen sie erst durch bewusste Sprechbetonung möglich. Üblich ist durchaus noch "nachdem ich ihm geholfen habe aufzuräumen", bzw. "nachdem ich beim Aufräumen geholfen habe".

Comment: Warum ich bei dem "aufräumen"-Beispiel lieber automatisch in den Infinitiv mit "zu" verfallen würde - also "geholfen habe aufzuräumen" -, ist mir auch nicht ganz klar. Aber es ist wie's ist. Hat da jemand eine Erklärung dafür?